# Searching GAE datastore properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I have a datastore entity `Foo` that has six properties `bar1`, `bar2`, `bar3`, `bar4`, `bar5` and  `bar6`. They contain a pair of values as shown below.

```
UserID   bar1   bar2   bar3   bar4   bar5   bar6
Mr. X    A,B    C,D    E,F    A,D    C,E,   B,F
Mr. Y    F,D    A,C    E,B    A,D    C,E    B,F
```

My goal is to check whether any given letter `A` or `B` or `C` or `D` or `E` or `F` appears in any property `bar1` or `bar2` or `bar3` or `bar4` or `bar5` or `bar6` for `Mr. X`.

I have read GAE's NDB Query documentation. I see that whether a property has any of multiple values i.e. whether `bar3 IN ['python', 'ruby', 'php']` is testable. But not a situation like `'python' IN [bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, bar5, bar6]`.

I have also read the complication arising out of the `repeated=True` case.

Need help to build the test in a most efficient way. 
Any help?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Seach API.  Or, perhaps add a ComputedProperty that is a concatenation of all the `barX` lists

Answer (score 0):

I agree with GAEFan that a ComputedPorperty or Search API would be preferable. But you could use ndb.or to get the job done without canging the model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Foo(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.StringProperty()
  bar1 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
  bar2 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
  bar3 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)

Foo(user='Mr X', bar1=['A','B'],bar2=['C','D'],bar3=['E','F']).put()
Foo(user='Mr Y', bar1=['F','D'],bar2=['B','C'],bar3=['E','B']).put()

for res in Foo.query(ndb.OR(Foo.bar1 == 'A', Foo.bar2 == 'A', Foo.bar3 == 'A')):
  print res.user
```

Outputs

```
"Mr X"
```